# Storyboard UITabBaar, initiate two different views from button

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I've created a storyboard that has a UITabbarController all is working well but now I want to add some logic that determines which viewcontroller a particular tabbar button will display.

Example... if a customer has a valid subscription display viewcontroller one, if no subscription display viewcontroller two.

Is this possible using storyboards, I've looked at UITabBarDelegate and prepareForSegue but struggling to piece this together?

Are there any examples of how to do this sort of thing using StoryBoards?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this:

```
if(hasSubscription)
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    ViewController1* subsection = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    ViewController2* subsection1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

    [(UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:subsection,subsection1, nil]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add rootviewController according to the subscription then above answer given by [soryngod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926884/soryngod) is good one.

But if you want to open viewControllers after rootviewcontroller loaded, then at tabBarButton press perform following code:-

before this code, add yours viewControllerONE and viewControllerTWO to the rootViewController by segues as shown: [image: Picture]. And give each segue an identifier in AttributeInspector, example "one" for viewControllerONE and "two" for viewControllerTWO.
then at tabBarButton action do the following:-

```
if(subscription)
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"one" sender:self];
      else
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"two" sender:self];
```